# DateTimePicker in modal popup no longer shows after cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I use the DateTimePicker plugin made by Trent Richardson in a modal popup, to select the date from which to archive items. All works fine when the modal pops up. In this modal I have two buttons: Archive and Cancel. 
If I select a date and press Archive, all works well and at the next pop up, the datetimepicker works fine.
However, if I press Cancel, the next time I use the popup, the datetimepicker doesn't work. Weirdest yet, I have another popup to show archived items that also has a datetimepicker. If I cancel the action in either popup, the datetimpicker will not show in neither popup.

Here's the code javascript to initialize the popup:

```
var modalBackground = $("#modalBackground");
var Notifications_ArchiveHolder = $("#Notifications_ArchiveHolder");
var Notifications_ShowArchivePopupHolder = $("#Notifications_ShowArchivePopupHolder");
var ArchiveURL = "@Url.Action("Archive")";
var ShowArchiveUrl = "@Url.Action("ShowArchive", "Notifications")";

function ArchivePopup() {        
    $.get(ArchiveURL, function (content) {
        if (Notifications_ArchiveHolder.html().length <= 10) {
            Notifications_ArchiveHolder.html(content);                
        }
    })
    InitArchivePopup();
}

function InitArchivePopup() {       
    modalBackground.show();

    //set up positon
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    var hh = Notifications_ArchiveHolder.height();
    var hw = Notifications_ArchiveHolder.width();
    var posx = (h / 2) - 100;
    var posy = (w / 2) - 200;
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.css("position", "fixed");
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.css("top", posx);
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.css("left", posy);                      

    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.show();

    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
}

function Cancel_Archive() {
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.hide();
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.html("");
    modalBackground.hide();
}
```

A div is used for the background and another to host the popup:

```
<div id="modalBackground" class="graphicScreen" style="display: none; position: fixed;   top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
<div id="Notifications_ArchiveHolder" style="background-color: white; display: none; z-index: 9999;"></div>
```

And the code for the partial view rendered in the popup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Resources/styles/Notifications/NotificationsPage.css")" />

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Archive", "Notifications", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="popupTitle">
    Archive notifications
</div>

<div class="popupNotifications">
    <span>Archive to date (inclusive)</span>
    <input type="text" name="olderThan" id="chooseDate" />
</div>
<div style="margin: 15px">
    <input class="goVariant" type="submit" value="Archive" />
    <input id="cancelBtn" class="goVariant" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel_Archive()" />
    @*<div class="tooltip_Holder" keyword="notif_admin_archive" onclick="showToolTip();"></div>*@
</div>
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Resources/styles/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css")"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/JQuery/DateTimePicker/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/JQuery/DateTimePicker/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/JQuery/DateTimePicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/JQuery/DateTimePicker/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js")"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chooseDate').datetimepicker();
})
</script>
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: where is Cancel_Archive() function jquery?

Comment: just scroll and you will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough clean-up of script files (no longer passing them from the partial view), it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following code. As you loading content on you modal so you need to use the live function which can be achieved  using the following code.

```
$('body').on('click','#chooseDate',function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It doesn't work. I managed to find a work around: I load the content of the popup just once, and when I close the popup I no longer erase the html of the popup from the containing div. It works.

Comment: Now, it works for one popup, but not for both: if I cancel one popup and repop it, datetimepicker shows, but the datetimepicker in the other popup will no longer show, until I refresh the page.